# Visual Studio Code How to change to windows terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to visual studio code and my terminal always shows integrated ubuntu LTS terminal in windows instead of windows terminal.

I searched google and followed some steps like Press F1 in the search entered "Terminal: Select Default Profile" and when i selected "windows command prompt" but still it shows ubuntu LTS terminal. How to change this to windows command prompt terminal.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it will set the default terminal

1. Press F1
2. Type "Terminal"
3. Select "Configure Terminal Settings"
4. Select "Integrated"

Answer (score 0):

Check this document, it should lead you to select integrated terminal.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal